# Is it possible to pull in data from a Facebook Page?

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I was wondering if it is possible to pull in data from a Facebook Page (not a profile page) to a wordpress blog?

Comment: what page do you have in mind exactly and which data do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Using the graph api, yes.  Check the documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page